# How do I align these separate pieces of text with two elements on the left and an element on the right?

Tags: css

I want to do this:

[image]

However I'm having some issues with trying to have the Blue Link, the summary text and the Severity all align and having the severity on the far right.

I currently have this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<div style={{ padding: 20, display: 'flex', 'justify-content': 'space-between' }}>
  <div>
    <p>
      <a id="hyperlink" target="_blank" href={link} style={{ paddingRight: 16}}>
        {element.key}
      </Hyperlink>

      {element.summary}
    </p>
           
    <a style={{ color: '#737373', 'font-size': '12px', 'line-height': '15px' }}>
      {element.severity.toUpperCase()}
    </a/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was told I have to use `justify-content: space-between` but it seems to not be working?

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: your code has irrelevant details and is wrong with a vs hyperlink. you should post essential only code.

Answer (score 1):

First of your code is a mess: You use a element that's no HTML5 element, forget to close multiple elements etc

As for the desired result, you have only 1 item within your flex box. 
Try the code blow to fix your issues

```css
.flex{
  padding: 20; 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.severity{
  color: #737373; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px;
}

#hyperlink{
  padding-right: 16px
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <p>
      <a id="hyperlink" target="_blank" href="{link}" >
        {element.key}
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div style="flex-grow:1;">
      <p>{element.summary}</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <p>
      <a class="severity">
        {element.severity.toUpperCase()}
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your html has for instance a p element inside that prohibits flexbox.

**flex-grow: 1** makes the middle element large once flexbox is in force.

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content:space-between">

      <a>CSFID</a>
      <a style="flex-grow:1">Multiselect</a>                     
      <a >MINOR</a>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wb104amk/1/